# AWS Glue Python Shell Job Fails with MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, pyarrow

I have AWS Glue Python Shell Job that fails after running for about a minute, processing 2 GB text file. The job does minor edits to the file like finding and removing some lines, removing last character in a line and adding carriage returns based on conditions. **Same job runs just fine for file sizes below 1 GB.**

- Job "Maximum capacity setting" is 1.
- "Max concurrency" is 2880.
- "Job timeout (minutes)" is 900.

Detailed failure message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise e_type(e_value).with_traceback(new_stack)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-9g022ft7/pysh-tf-bb-to-parquet.py", line 134, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Actual python code that I am trying to run:

```
import boto3
import json
import os
import sys
from sys import getsizeof
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import os
import psutil
import io 
import pandas as pd 
import pyarrow as pa #not supported by glue
import pyarrow.parquet as pq #not supported by glue
import s3fs #not supported by glue

#Object parameters (input and output).
s3region = 'reducted' 
s3bucket_nm = 'reducted' 

#s3 inbound object parameters.
s3object_inbound_key_only = 'reducted' 
s3object_inbound_folder_only = 'reducted' 
s3object_inbound_key = s3object_inbound_folder_only + '/' + s3object_inbound_key_only 

#s3 object base folder parameter.
s3object_base_folder = s3object_inbound_key_only[:-9].replace('.', '_')

#s3 raw object parameters.
s3object_raw_key_only = s3object_inbound_key_only
s3object_raw_folder_only = 'reducted' + s3object_base_folder
s3object_raw_key = s3object_raw_folder_only + '/' + s3object_inbound_key_only

#s3 PSV object parameters.
s3object_psv_key_only = s3object_inbound_key_only + '.psv'
s3object_psv_folder_only = 'reducted' + s3object_base_folder + '_psv'
s3object_psv_key = s3object_psv_folder_only + '/' + s3object_psv_key_only
s3object_psv_crawler = s3object_base_folder + '_psv'

glue_role = 'reducted'

processed_immut_db = 'reducted'

#Instantiate s3 client.
s3client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    region_name = s3region
)

#Instantiate s3 resource.
s3resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    region_name = s3region
)

#Store raw object metadata as a dictionary variable.
s3object_raw_dict = {
    'Bucket': s3bucket_nm,
    'Key': s3object_inbound_key
}

#Create raw file object.
s3object_i = s3client.get_object(
    Bucket = s3bucket_nm,
    Key = s3object_raw_folder_only + '/' + s3object_raw_key_only
)

#Initialize the list to hold the raw file data string.
l_data = []

#Load s_data string into a list and transform.
for line in (''.join((s3object_i['Body'].read()).decode('utf-8'))).splitlines():
    #Once the line with the beginning of the field list tag is reached, re-initialize the list.
    if line.startswith('START-OF-FIELDS'):
        l_data = []
    #Load (append) the input file into the list.
    l_data.append(line + '\n')
    #Once the line with the end of the field list tag is reached, remove the field metadata tags.
    if line.startswith('END-OF-FIELDS'):
    #Remove the blank lines.
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if '\n' != line]
        #Remove lines with #.
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if '#' not in line]
        #Remove the tags signifying the the start and end of the field list.
        l_data.remove('START-OF-FIELDS\n')
        l_data.remove('END-OF-FIELDS\n')
        #Remove the new line characters (\n) from each field name (assuming the last character in each element).
        l_data=list(map(lambda i: i[:-1], l_data))
        #Insert "missing" field names in the beginning of the header.
        l_data.insert(0, 'BB_FILE_DT')
        l_data.insert(1, 'BB_ID')
        l_data.insert(2, 'RETURN_CD')
        l_data.insert(3, 'NO_OF_FIELDS')
        #Add | delimiter to each field.
        l_data=[each + "|" for each in l_data]
        #Concatenate all header elements into a single element.
        l_data = [''.join(l_data[:])]
    #Once the line with the end of data dataset tag is reached, remove the dataset metadata tags.
    if line.startswith('END-OF-FILE'):
        #Remove TIMESTARTED metadata.
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if 'TIMESTARTED' not in line]
        #Remove lines with #.
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if '#' not in line]
        #Remove the tags signifying the the start and end of the dataset.
        l_data.remove('START-OF-DATA\n')
        l_data.remove('END-OF-DATA\n')
        #Remove DATARECORDS metadata.
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if 'DATARECORDS' not in line]
        #Remove TIMEFINISHED metadata.
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if 'TIMEFINISHED' not in line]
        #Remove END-OF-FILE metadata.
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if 'END-OF-FILE' not in line]

#Store the file header into a variable.
l_data_header=l_data[0][:-1] + '\n'

#Add the column with the name of the inbound file to all elements of the file body.
l_data_body=[s3object_inbound_key_only[-8:] + '|' + line[:-2] + '\n' for line in l_data[2:]]

#Combine the file header and file body into a single list.
l_data_body.insert(0, l_data_header)

#Load the transformed list into a string variable.
s3object_o_data = ''.join(l_data_body)

#Write the transformed list from a string variable to a new s3 object.
s3resource.Object(s3bucket_nm, s3object_psv_folder_only + '/' + s3object_psv_key_only).put(Body=s3object_o_data)
```

I have determined that the "MemoryError" is caused by the line of code below. s3object_i_data_decoded contains the 2 GB file I've mentioned about earlier. Total memory occupied by the python process prior to execution of this line of code is 2.025 GB. Looks like memory usage jumps dramatically after this line of code runs:

```
#Load the transformed list into a string variable.
s3object_o_data = ''.join(l_data_body)
```

After measuring the process memory size during the run of the code, I found that whenever a list variable is loaded into another variable, the amount of memory used almost quadruples. So 2 GB list variable when assigned to another variable cause the process to memory size grow to 6+ GB. :/

I am also assuming Glue Python Shell Jobs have difficulty handling files exceeding 2GB size range ... can anyone confirm this?

1. Has anyone else experienced this error when processing files larger than 2 GB?
2. Are there any tweaks can be done to the job to avoid this "MemoryError"?
3. Are 2 GB data sets just too large for Glue Python Shell Job and perhaps the Glue Spark should be considered.

I could theoretically partition the job into smaller batches via the code itself, but wanted to see if there is lower hanging fruit.

I'd really like to tweak the existing job and avoid using Glue Spark for this, if not necessary.

Thanks in advance to everyone for sharing their ideas! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you could show the code snippet that would be great.
1 DPU provides you 
4 vcores
16 GB memory
which is more than enough to process your data.

The best you can do is read the file as StreamingBody and than perform your operations in chunks.
You can refer it [here](https://medium.com/@jnshubham/demystifying-aws-lambda-deal-with-large-files-stored-on-s3-using-python-and-boto3-6078d0e2b9df?source=friends_link&sk=6805b48d20d6602e0b1ec59f98134ea5)

Basically, it is best if you utilize the Streaming capabilities of s3.

Else more insight can be shared if you share how you are reading and writing file as 2GB file is no big deal here.

I have multiple suggestions and if you wish you can implement them:
1. Instead of reading the whole file into memory load it line by line as you are processing it.

```
for line in s3object_i['Body'].iter_lines():
```

2. You are using list comprehension again and again just for filtering the data instead you can create a compound statement as this increases the time complexity of your code and be optimized like

```
    if line.startswith('END-OF-FIELDS'):
        l_data.insert(0, 'BB_FILE_DT')
        l_data.insert(1, 'BB_ID')
        l_data.insert(2, 'RETURN_CD')
        l_data.insert(3, 'NO_OF_FIELDS')
        l_data=[line + "|" for line in l_data if ('' != line) and ('#' not in line)]
        l_data.remove('START-OF-FIELDS')
        l_data.remove('END-OF-FIELDS')
        l_data = [''.join(l_data[:])]

#and
    if line.startswith('END-OF-FILE'):
        l_data.remove('START-OF-DATA')
        l_data.remove('END-OF-DATA')
        l_data=[line for line in l_data if ('TIMESTARTED' not in line) and ('#' not in line) and ('DATARECORDS' not in line) and ('TIMEFINISHED' not in line) and ('END-OF-FILE' not in line)]
```

3. For saving the file back to s3, you can leverage multipart upload or you can create a generator object instead of list and then yield the results to s3.
   like

```
def uploadFileS3():
#for uploading 25 mb chunks to s3
    config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024*25, max_concurrency=10,
                        multipart_chunksize=1024*25, use_threads=True)

    s3_client.upload_file(file, S3_BUCKET, key,
    Config = config,
    Callback=ProgressPercentage(''.join(l_data))
    )


------------------------------------------------------------
#or a bit tricky to implement but worth it
------------------------------------------------------------
def file_stream():
    for line in l_data:
        yield line

# we have to keep track of all of our parts
part_info_dict = {'Parts': []}
# start the multipart_upload process
multi_part_upload = s3.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=temp_key)

# Part Indexes are required to start at 1
for part_index, line in enumerate(file_stream(), start=1):
    # store the return value from s3.upload_part for later
    part = s3.upload_part(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=temp_key,
        # PartNumber's need to be in order and unique
        PartNumber=part_index,
        # This 'UploadId' is part of the dict returned in multi_part_upload
        UploadId=multi_part_upload['UploadId'],
        # The chunk of the file we're streaming.
        Body=line,
    )

    # PartNumber and ETag are needed
    part_info_dict['Parts'].append({
        'PartNumber': part_index,
        # You can get this from the return of the uploaded part that we stored earlier
        'ETag': part['ETag']
    })

    # This what AWS needs to finish the multipart upload process
    completed_ctx = {
        'Bucket': bucket_name,
        'Key': temp_key,
        'UploadId': multi_part_upload['UploadId'],
        'MultipartUpload': part_info_dict
    }

# Complete the upload. This triggers Amazon S3 to rebuild the file for you.
# No need to manually unzip all of the parts ourselves!
s3.complete_multipart_upload(**completed_ctx)
```

If you can implement these changes then you can process even 5GB file also in glue python shell. The key is to better optimize the code.

Hope you get the point.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I've updated my original post and added the line of code after which the MemoryError message comes up: s_data = ''.join(s3object_i_data_decoded)

Comment: so assuming you are converting your generator object to string is throwing the error. There might be possibilities of improving the code itself but can't help without the complete picture.

Comment: I've added the "complete picture". Hope you can help @shubham-jain !